# flex does not center long lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make an array of "buttons" with links.
It works fine when the text is only one line, but if the text wraps to two lines, the lines get left justified.
I'd rather have both lines centered.

```css
.brand-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Montserrat, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.brand {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 31%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: solid 3px white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.brand A {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6f6f6f;
    line-height: normal;
}
a {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-wrap">
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">Short</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">words</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">gets centered</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">Both horizontally</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">and vertically</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">But long sentences get left-justified</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.brand-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Montserrat, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.brand {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 31%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: solid 3px white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.brand A {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  line-height: normal;
}

a {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-wrap">
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">Short</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">words</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">gets centered</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">Both horizontally</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">and vertically</a></div>
  <div class="brand"><a href="#">But long sentences <b>DON'T</b> get left-justified</a></div>
</div>
```

The problem with your code was that because it overflowed, the container expanded to the maximum possible width, making it *appear* as if the text wasn't center-aligned. Adding a `text-align:center` fixes that problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding `justify-content: center;` or `align-items: center;`
on your flexbox container!

Comment: They already have.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand correctly. It seemed to me that .brand was contained by .brand-wrap, not the opposite!

Comment: Yes, they both have flexbox, however, the problem was with the inner 'flexing' of .brand.